# Injective function from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\operatorname{Eq}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am asked to show that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| \leq |\operatorname{Eq}(\mathbb{N})|$ by showing there exists an injective function $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\to \operatorname{Eq}(\mathbb{N})$, where $\operatorname{Eq}(\mathbb{N})$ are the equivalence relations on $\mathbb{N}$, or equivalently the partitions of $\mathbb{N}$.

My intuition says $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\to \operatorname{Eq}(\mathbb{N}):A\mapsto \{A \cup(\mathbb{N} \setminus A)\}$ should work but I don’t know how even start a proof.

If I’m correct, how can I prove it? If not, what function would work?

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed the error

Comment: I think I fixed it!

Comment: Use $A$ instead of $n$ to denote subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, as the latter is reserved for _elements_ of $\mathbb{N}$. Also, the extra braces and union are unnecessary. The definition of $f$ should thus be changed to $A \mapsto \{A, \mathbb{N} \setminus A\}$.

Comment: Or $A\mapsto\{A+1,\ \mathbb N\setminus(A+1)\}$ where $A+1=\{a+1:a\in A\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll use the notation "$A+n$" to denote $\{a+n \mid a \in A\}$.

Define
$$
f(A) =
\begin{cases}
      \{A+2, (\mathbb N \setminus A)+2, \{1\}, \{2\}\} & \text{if  } 1 \in A\\
      \{A+2, (\mathbb N \setminus A)+2, \{1, 2\} \}          & \text{if  } 1 \not\in A\\
\end{cases}
$$

The "obvious" answer is $f(A) = \{A, \mathbb N \setminus A\}$, but unfortunately this maps $A$ and $\mathbb N \setminus A$ to the same equivalence - this is a two-to-one mapping, not a one-to-one mapping.

So we "cheat" this map a bit, by shifting our set and its complement two units to the right, which frees up $1$ and $2$, and then we use those two numbers to "encode" which of $A$ or $\mathbb N \setminus A$ produced the partition of $\mathbb N +2$.

Alternatively, @user14111 provided a drastically simpler way to 'tag which set was used to create the partition', by defining
$$f(A)=\{A+1,\ \mathbb N\setminus(A+1)\}.$$

With this map, the partition element that contains $1$ must have come from the complement of the (shifted) set.

Comment: Does this assume 0 is a member of the naturals?

Comment: Mine assumes that it is not, though it could be easily tweaked if you did, and the one from user14111 doesn't care.